# Como recuperar el id del ultimo registro en php a mysql?

Tags: php

Buen día a todos  necesito me asesoren de como puedo hacer esto:
Estoy haciendo un insert normal desde PHP a una BD en MYSQL, pero **necesito el ID (que es autoincremental) de ese registro para luego con ese ID insertar otros campos en una tabla relacionada**, algo similar a registrar una factura-> obtener el id_factura y con este registrar los productos correspondientes en una tabla intermedia de una relación de muchos a muchos..

Comment: Agrega el código de la consulta a la pregunta pulsando el enlace [edit] que aparece a pie de pregunta. Así podremos ver como la estas haciendo y decirte que función debes usar, normalmente la `$mysqli->insert_id` o bien `$dbh->lastInsertId();`  si es pdo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de realizar la inserción una alternativa que puedes usar es: 
 hacer `SELECT MAX(id) FROM mi_tabla`.